# How to create an efficient conditional layer in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I have a resnet50 model that outputs a class prediction (1, 2 or 3). Based on the output of the classifier, I want to make another prediction that selects the next model based on the class prediction.

This is what I have so far.

```py
import torch

class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model1 = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1, bias=False)
        torch.nn.init.ones_(self.model1.weight)

        self.model2 = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1, bias=False)
        torch.nn.init.ones_(self.model2.weight)

        self.model3 = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1, bias=False)
        torch.nn.init.ones_(self.model3.weight)

    def forward(self, x):
        
        # Get batch_size
        batch_size = x.size(1)
        output = torch.zeros(batch_size, 1, device=x.device)
        
        # Loop over every value in batch
        for i in range(batch_size):
            value = x[:, i]
            if value == 1:
                output[i] = self.model1(value)
            elif value == 2:
                output[i] = self.model2(value)
            else:
                output[i] = self.model3(value)

        return output
```

```
model = SimpleModel()

output = model(torch.tensor([[1,2,3]], dtype=torch.float32))
output
```

My concern is that I am only computing one forward pass on each iteration of the loop which seems very inefficient. What happens if I increase the batch size to 64? Will the forward pass be computed in parallel?

Any thoughts/ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows. The code runs each one of the three models just once by using masks as conditions without using any for loop:

```
def forward(self, x):
        
        # Get batch_size
        batch_size = x.size(1)
        output = torch.zeros(batch_size, 1, device=x.device)
        
        # Compute one mask for each condition

        value_mask_1 = (x == 1)
        value_mask_2 = (x == 2)
        value_mask_3 = (x == 3)
        
        # Then just run the model on the items selected by each condition's mask.
        # And then assign model's outputs to the corresponding positions in the output variable.

        output[value_mask_1.view_as(output)] = self.model1(x[value_mask_1])
        output[value_mask_2.view_as(output)] = self.model1(x[value_mask_2])
        output[value_mask_3.view_as(output)] = self.model1(x[value_mask_3])

        return output
```